# Write into HDFS based on log level

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hdfs, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using HDFS bolt to write log messages into HDFS. Now all log messages with different log levels like WARN,DEBUG,INFO,ERROR are writing into same file. How can I write INFO messages in one file, WARN messages in another file, ERROR messages alone in one more file in HDFS? I am using log4j Kafka appender. Basically I need to write log messages into different files based on the log levels like INFO,ERROR and DEBUG.,

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution should be to use four `HdfsBolt`s and one additional "LogSplitBolt" the emits four output streams (one for each log level):

```java
public class LogSplitBolt {
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        Fields schema = new Fields(...);
        declarer.declareStream("debug", schema);
        declarer.declareStream("error", schema);
        declarer.declareStream("warnings", schema);
        declarer.declareStream("info", schema);
   }

   public void execute(Tuple input) {
       String logLevel = input.getXXX(...); // get log level
       // use logLevel as output streamId
       collector.emit(logLevel, new Values(input.getValues());
    }
}
```

When you build your topology, the different `HdfsBolt`s subscribe to different streams:

```java
builder.addBolt("splitter", new LogSplitBolt());
builder.addbolt("writeDebug", new HdfsBolt(...)).localOfShuffle("debug", "splitter");
builder.addbolt("writeError", new HdfsBolt(...)).localOfShuffle("error", "splitter");
builder.addbolt("writeWarning", new HdfsBolt(...)).localOfShuffle("warning", "splitter");
builder.addbolt("writeInfo", new HdfsBolt(...)).localOfShuffle("info", "splitter");
```

Of course, each `HdfsBolt` is configured to its own file in HDFS.

Comment: Yes, or you could just write a single bolt that does all of that.